# C# Task Scheduler in Remote Machine

Tags: c#, taskscheduler, taskservice

I'm trying to set up a program that would create a task schedule in a remote server. The following code works fine for local machine however when I try it with the remote server, it throws up the following error.

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The request is not
>   supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070032)'

```
void SetupDailyTask()
    {
        using (TaskService ts = new TaskService("servername.us.xxxxxdomain.com",
            @"domainname\username","domainname","password"))
        {
            //Task tsk = ts.GetTask("DailyTask");
            //if (tsk != null) { ts.RootFolder.DeleteTask("DailyTask"); }

            //DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            //TimeSpan tsp = new TimeSpan(12, 44, 0);
            //dt = dt.Date + tsp;
            //ts.Execute("notepad.exe").Once().Starting(dt).AsTask("DailyTask");
        }
    }
```

I've already tested the credentials, server name etc and they work just fine with the Remote Desktop Connection. I'm using the `Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler` namespace. Any help with this is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the OS on the remote machine?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean It is Windows Server 2003.

Comment: taskscheduler.codeplex.com not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/taskservice),  this is only supported on Windows Server 2008 or newer.

One [option](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/814596/how-to-use-schtasks-exe-to-schedule-tasks-in-windows-server-2003) I found was provided by Microsoft, but I've not tried it.

Comment: Thank you Sean. I might have overlooked it. Any workarounds for this..?? I really need to set this schedule up in the server.

Comment: @KarthikeyanNatarajan updated answer with possible work around

Comment: I tried the Schtasks to set up the scheduled task in the remote server however it produced the ERROR - The request is not supported. The format that I used was : schtasks /run /s servername.us.domainname /u username /p password /I /TN "Test"